On Off RFID Tag
Who can help or give an idea how to build a presence sensor using an RFID chip connected to a physical button.
The idea is to use it like an wireless presence sensor that will use no electricity, but it will be read by the antenna from a distance of about 5 m.

Where does the button come in?

Additional detail of how it will be used would help. More than one tag? Mobile? Have you found RFID tags that work at 5 meters? Multiple receivers OK if needed.

If you interrupt or shield the RFID antenna track it either fail or work over FAR shorter range. Your button MIGHT be able to be a shield which the press action moves clear of the tag.
